# Set cell width and hight to normal even though i copy a large text.file into it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a text file into a cell, and everything works except that the cells AutoFit, which I don't want it to. I want it to stay the same width, but I am not sure how to do this. I guess it should be under  `Set SNRCode = Range("B2")` but I have tried to both set the cell values and cancel `autofit`.

```
Dim arkNavne As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim navn As String
Dim i As Long
Dim SNRCode As Range
Dim matchCell As Range
Dim targetSNR As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Overview").Activate
Set arkNavne = Range("B4:B14")
For Each cell In arkNavne

    navn = cell.Value
    Worksheets(navn).Activate
    

    Set SNRCode = Range("B2")
    
    For i = 1 To 500
        If SNRCode <> "" Then
            targetSNR = "_" & SNRCode.Value & ".lic"
            
        
            Set matchCell = Worksheets("FilesImport").Range("A1:A200").Find(targetSNR, Lookat:=xlPart)
            If matchCell Is Nothing Then
                    SNRCode.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NO MATCH"

                Else
                    SNRCode.Offset(0, 1).Value = matchCell.Value
                    
            
                    With matchCell.Font
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
            End If
            
            Set SNRCode = SNRCode.Offset(0, 2)
                
        Else
            Set SNRCode = SNRCode.Offset(0, 1)
        
        End If
        
    Next i
    
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: `MyCell.WrapText = False` `MyCell` being a range or in your case `SNRCode`.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be a handy site for you, [explaining different ways to set column width](https://hubpages.com/technology/Setting-Column-Width-and-Using-AutoFit-in-Excel-and-VBA#:%7E:text=VBA%3A%20Set%20Column%20Width%20and%20AutoFit%20in%20Excel,The%20End%20Result%208%20Ready%20to%20Proceed.%20)

`Columns("A").ColumnWidth=10` or `Columns(1).ColumnWidth=10`

`Range("B2").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth=10` or `Cells(2,2).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth=10`

You can also capture multiple rows by using " : ", for example

`Columns(A:Z).ColumnWidth=10`